# How to drop packet before full download

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I'm creating a personal app for network filtering using C. I already know that you can log and analyze a downloaded packet's info using this code:

```
tcpPacket = recvfrom(raw_socket , buffer , 65536 , 0 , &serverAddress , &serverAddressSize);
```

but this requires that the tcp packet be downloaded first. What I need is that the filter will be acted out even before it is downloaded, let's say it examines the source IP and based on that, it either accepts or rejects it.

Note: Yes I am aware of iptables, but I do not want to use it because I want to learn how to do it using raw sockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got what I needed now. I need to call getpeername(2) after accepting a connection http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpeername.2.html.

Answer (score 0):

In a packet-oriented network (like TCP/IP is), the each packet contains *both* address information and actual payload.

So it doesn't make sense to say that you want to drop the packet before it's downloaded, based on data that is *in the packet*.

It would perhaps be imaginable if you could stop the actual (hardware) receiver mid-packet, but I don't think any "normal" networking hardware or APIs expose such functionality.

Comment: What I am attempting to achieve is a "mini firewall". Actually it is more accurate to say "first generation firewall". From Wikipedia: " If a packet matches the packet filter's set of filtering rules, the packet filter will drop (silently discard) the packet or reject it (discard it, and send "error responses" to the source)." - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_%28computing%29#First_generation:_packet_filters

Ergo I am sure someone has already done it before.

Comment: @chelem7 - This is typically done placing a filter into the network stack so that the (complete) packet can be examined before optionally forwarding it to the rest of the network stack. Search for `iptables` and `netfilter`.